# Segmentation fault with robot.js

Tags: node.js, robotjs

I am getting this error with https://npm.im/robotjs
`[1]    76506 segmentation fault  node index.js`
Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating node. I was at version 12.14.1 and was getting that same error. Now at v12.18.3 robotjs works just fine.